# last time a table was accessed in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Is it possible to determine when the last time a table was accessed in Oracle?
 I am trying this, but this will not include when was the last time the table was selected.

```
select * from dba_objects;
```

Comment: Tom had already answered this question --> https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2613235100346955813

Answer (score 1):

```
select p.object_owner owners, p.object_name Obj_Name, p.operation Operation, 
p.options Options, count(1) Idx_Usg_Cnt 
from dba_hist_sql_plan p,dba_hist_sqlstat s 
where p.object_owner = '&amp;USERNAME' and p.operation like 'TABLE%' 
and p.sql_id = s.sql_id and p.object_name=’&amp;OBJNAME’ 
group by p.object_owner,p.object_name,p.operation,p.options order by 1,2,3
```

Answer (score 1):

From @KD 's answer I've developed this query to detect unused tables:

```
select a.obj#, b.object_name, b.owner, b.object_type, b.timestamp
    from dba_hist_seg_stat a, dba_objects b
    where a.obj# = b.object_id
    and   b.owner = 'YOUR_SCHEMA_NAME'
    and object_name = 'A_TABLE_NAME'
order by timestamp desc
```

Since this query makes use of SYS user views, you must have special privileges to run it. If you have them, you can have a look at dba_hist_XXX views, or only have a look at the rest of the columns in the views used here: you have info about reads, writes, locks and many more.

**EDIT**: Thanks to @APC for the warning. DBA_HIST_XXX are views from Diagnostics Pack that require **special license**.

Comment: Please note that the `DBA_HIST_%` views are populated by AWR. This is part of the Diagnostics pack, which requires an additional licence on top of Enterprise Edition. If you use any of these views without licensing the Diagnostics pack you are in breach of Oracle's T&Cs and Oracle may sue your organisation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the SQL below to find the list of segments getting full table scaned and how many times 
they have been full table scanned..is this SQL is correct with respect to this.

```
    select a.obj#,a.table_scans_delta,b.object_name,b.owner,b.object_type 
    from dba_hist_seg_stat a, dba_objects b
    where a.obj# = b.object_id
    and   b.owner like 'USERNAMES%'
    order by table_scans_total desc
```

Comment: Please note that the DBA_HIST_% views are populated by AWR. This is part of the Diagnostics pack, which requires an additional licence on top of Enterprise Edition. If you use any of these views without licensing the Diagnostics pack you are in breach of Oracle's T&Cs and Oracle may sue your organisation.